# Can't simulate simulink model

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, matlab, pid-controller

[image] I'm trying to simulate the following chopper controlled dc motor in MATLAB Simulink using a PI controller.
Now without the freewheeling/flyback diode across the motor terminals I can simulate the model to get the desired speed output. But with the diode the motor seems to run at full speed and is uncontrollabe.
Is it a glitch in the software? or is there anything I can do about it in the software?

Comment: When you see something unexpected then for sure it must be a bug in the software. It cannot be that anything unexpected is happening in your design, **or can it?** You're using **models** of components. Do be aware of this statement about models: "All models are **wrong**, but some are **useful**". I suggest that you investigate what is happening precisely. **Why** does the diode influence behavior when it should not. **Why** should the diode not influence the behavior? Hint: it should be operating in....  Is it operating like that or not?

Comment: A doubt if we use a flyback diode won't the motor experience a breaking torque during pwm off period? Is that desirable?

Comment: I would look carefully at how the diode is modeled. It sounds like ti is acting like something other than a normal diode.